# How to make a script that launches bash command but don't open it?

Tags: bash, scripts, mono

So I built this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u matas 
cd /home/matas/Desktop/Release
mono launch.exe
```

How I can make this to launch `'mono launch.exe'` but not open bash?
I know It is possible.

Comment: Have you tried adding executable bit and double clicking on the script?

Comment: I created name.sh  put code, and I clicking 'run in terminal'

Comment: Oh. So I need to click 'execute', but how I can make this automaticlly? I dont need that window which lets me choose.

Comment: Run: `chmod +x name.sh` see if it works... for me it does not show anything just runs the script.

Comment: What's your goal, really ? You want to just double click the script and run? or you want to run it in GUI ? Why do you need `sudo -u` there ?  Is your user not `matas` ? Please clarify

Comment: I do need sudo - u because this program runs at encrypted mode (whatever it is), I need to enter sudo password in bash, and when logging in I need to do it too. CHModing does nothing. In ubuntu i did sth in nautilus settings, or file manager settings.

Comment: And yes i need to run it in gui, without cli.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I am undertanding, you want the script opened, but don't want to see the terminal. When you use function *run in terminal*, the ideia is open a terminal and execute there, once you can see the output.

should be better turn it on an executable with

```
chmod +x filename.sh
```

then you could tun that as an executable script with no need of terminal.

Comment: I think your problem is not chmod, but the file manager you are using.

What happen when you click the file to run? It opens in file editor or run with terminal?

Comment: It let me choose, open in terminal or execute. I click execute, it works - no bash, but i dont want that window.

Comment: Ok, unfortunately that window is from file manager. A good sugestion is put an extension to this file if you dont have one, when you open it and the window shows, say you want to run and to don't ask again (or anything like this is showed in your ubuntu version). With the extension, a file type is understood, this way you should not be asked again for this file and files with these extensions.